# couldn't create free space in vagrant

Tags: vagrant, size

I tried different commands available on net to resolve the space issue in my vagrant, but nothing working. Getting the below error:

```
[root@oracle-19c-vagrant vagrant]# lvextend -An -L+10G --resizefs /dev/mapper/vg_main-lv_root

Insufficient free space: 2560 extents needed, but only 0 available

[root@oracle-19c-vagrant vagrant]# lvresize -L +10G /dev/mapper/vg_main-lv_root

Couldn't create temporary archive name.

[root@oracle-19c-vagrant vagrant]# vgdisplay vg_main

  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg_main
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <36.51 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              9346
  Alloc PE / Size       9346 / <36.51 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               vIfWQh-yqA1-2pip-d9k9-20jV-tccP-wJP0Or
```

I got into this situation, as I loaded lot of data into Oracle which is running on Vagrant.

Please guide how to proceed to get the issue resolved. Thanks

I tried to increase the vagrant space from 60GB to 100GB by increasing in Vagrantfile as below, which also didnt helped:

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  # Use vagrant-env plugin if available
  if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-env")
  config.disksize.size = '100GB'
  config.env.load(".env.local", ".env") # enable the plugin
end
```